# GStreamer GstMeta is lost when using video scaling

Tags: metadata, gstreamer

I am trying carry over some custom SEI messages that I am parsing in gsth264parse.c by using Closed Captions metadata.

This is my pipeline

```
filesrc location=test_sei.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! vaapih264dec ! vaapipostproc width=320 height=200 format=yv12 ! appsink sync=false name=sink
```

So I call

```
gst_buffer_add_video_caption_meta(buffer,GST_VIDEO_CAPTION_TYPE_CEA608_RAW, "test", 5);
```

to add metadata to a GstBuffer.

Then, later on in my appsink code I call

```
gst_buffer_get_video_caption_meta(buffer)
```

to get my SEI message.

If I have video resizing in my pipeline, I receive NULL. If I remove  `width=320 height=200`, it works fine. Tried with `decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240`, same thing, if I remove resizing, it works. How to make GStreamer to preserve GstMeta of GstBuffer during video scaling?